# Booting root filesystem on LVM

Tags: debian, lvm, boot, root

I can't seem to make this work (or find info on the internet on the issue). Are there any additional settings when creating initramfs with the root filesystem on lvm?

This should be the settup:

```
 /boot -> bootable ext3, containing the kernels
 / -> root on lvm, jfs
 /usr -> usr on lvm, jfs
 /var -> var on lvm, jfs
```

I am working with debian squeeze, kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64, lvm2.

Comment: I don't work much with Debian, but in general, you need to make sure your initramfs environments includes all the necessary kernel modules -- that's typically the LVM modules, the appropriate filesystem modules (jfs), and whatever block device drivers (e.g., a scsi driver, etc).

Comment: I don't use debian, but i guess it should have a directory /usr/share/initramfs-tools and there there is a file called modules where you can add modules to be included. Your problem are the lvm modules. Then you can update the initram image - check here: http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-initrd.html

Comment: It *should* just work automatically if you have installed everything with the Debian tools in the Debian way (no custom kernel etc).

Comment: Are you sure that it is about LVM and not about **JFS**? Do you have any relevant boot messages? There seems to be a JFS related Debian bug report which could be related at: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=596391

Answer (score 1):

Do you install this setup from debian-installer? If yes, this should be a bug, which you should report[1].

If your change your system with some external tool like a live-cd or else, then you must run inside the fully mounted changeroot environment ( be aware of /proc & /dev in changeroot)

```
# update-initramfs -u -k all
```

I'm not sure about using jfs as root filesystem, but this should run well.

[1] http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting